# keepState property of ExtLib Navigator control doesn't work

Tags: xpages

I'm testing the Navigator control in Extension Library inside an App Layout control. The nav on the main XPage has two container nodes each containing two page nodes. The page nodes each lead to a plain XPage with a single "Return" button with a simple action to load the main page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">

        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration
                pageWidth="fluid" fixedNavbar="fixed-top" collapseLeftColumn="true" legal="false"
                placeBar="false" titleBar="false" footer="false">
                <xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode label="Page 1" />
                    <xe:pageTreeNode label="Page 2" />
                </xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks>
            </xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration>
        </xe:this.configuration>

        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:div xp:key="LeftColumn">
                <xe:navigator id="navigator1" keepState="true" expandable="true">
                    <xe:this.treeNodes>
                        <xe:basicContainerNode label="Container 1">
                            <xe:this.children>
                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="a1" page="/a1.xsp" />
                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="a2" page="/a2.xsp" />
                            </xe:this.children>
                        </xe:basicContainerNode>
                        <xe:basicContainerNode label="Container 2">
                            <xe:this.children>
                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="a1" page="/a1.xsp" />
                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="a2" page="/a2.xsp" />
                            </xe:this.children>
                        </xe:basicContainerNode>
                    </xe:this.treeNodes>
                </xe:navigator>
            </xp:div>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:applicationLayout>
</xp:view>
```

The `keepState` property is set to `true` but if I collapse one of the containers and go to a different page, the container reopens and does not keep its state when I return. This happens whether I use the browser's Back button or the Return button on the secondary page.

Am I misinterpreting the `keepState` property or is it broken? I have done searches on Google and OpenNTF and have not found anything about this problem.

Comment: The code is available on Github. You can take a look and see if you can find out what 'keepState' is used for: https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/search?q=keepstate&unscoped_q=keepstate.

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten The code shows that is the intended functionality so it appears to be a bug. Do you think it's worth reporting to HCL? Not sure if they are bothering to fix XPages code.

Comment: you could create an issue in the Github project and hope that some open source contributor (or someone from HCL) wants to take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the code on Github as Per suggested and that is indeed the intended functionality:

> Defines if collapsed or expanded state of items should be saved between server requests

Since it appears to be broken, I came up with a workaround using the navigator's `onItemClick` event to save state in a `sessionScope.navState` variable.  I store each container's state as an entry in a hashmap in a single `sessionScope` var to avoid multiple vars for multiple containers. Each container's `expanded` property is then loaded from `sessionScope.navState.[container name]`.

However, it has two drawbacks:

1. When returning to the navigator page, state is restored only when
   the page is directly reloaded/refreshed. State is NOT restored when using the browser's Back button.
2. Apparently the twisty is a separate link from the text of the container. The state is saved when the text is clicked but not the twisty, and access to the twisty is not exposed in the control's properties.

The updated code is below, slightly edited for brevity. Ideas for the drawbacks are welcome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
//initialize navigator state
if (sessionScope.navState == null) {
    sessionScope.navState = new java.util.HashMap();
    sessionScope.navState.put("c1", false);
    sessionScope.navState.put("c2", false);
}}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">

        <xe:this.configuration>
           [...]
        </xe:this.configuration>

        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:div xp:key="LeftColumn">
                <xe:navigator id="navigator1" keepState="true" expandable="true">

                    <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="navigator1">
                        <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var entry = context.getSubmittedValue();
sessionScope.navState.put(entry, !sessionScope.navState.get(entry));
}]]></xe:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>

                    <xe:this.treeNodes>
                        <xe:basicContainerNode label="Container 1"
                            submitValue="c1" expanded="#{javascript:sessionScope.navState.c1}">
                            <xe:this.children>
                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="hello" page="/a1.xsp" />
                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="goodbye" page="/a2.xsp" />
                            </xe:this.children>
                        </xe:basicContainerNode>
                        <xe:basicContainerNode label="Container 2"
                            submitValue="c2" expanded="#{javascript:sessionScope.navState.c2}">
                            <xe:this.children>
                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="hello" page="/a1.xsp" />
                                <xe:pageTreeNode label="goodbye" page="/a2.xsp" />
                            </xe:this.children>
                        </xe:basicContainerNode>
                    </xe:this.treeNodes>
                </xe:navigator>
            </xp:div>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:applicationLayout>
</xp:view>
```